# Redux, store same value more than once

Tags: reactjs, redux

I 'd like to avoid saving same data more than once in redux state, but not sure how to do it.

I'm working on search UI

Search query I send to server includes query string, filters, and sorting preference.

Conceptually they are all search parameters and I'd like to keep them in `searchParams` state in redux store.

However, some of the data are already in the redux store for another reason.
For instance, I maintain `viewSettings` state where I control which fields to show in the search result, and some of the filters (which are also in `searchParams`) are included in the `viewSettings`

It 's like DB normalizing, how do you normalize(?) your data in your redux store?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if object has same values by doing so, perhaps checking searchParams would be enough in you case.

```
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';
import { YOUR_ACTION } from '../actions/ActionTypes';

export default function (state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case YOUR_ACTION:
     if(!isEqual(state.key), action.payload){
      return state
        .set(key, action.payload);
     }
     return state;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to normalize your store  dataa structure when you call reducer to set data in the store. Use either [normalir](https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr) npm or you can use functional programming (map, set, filter or reducer function ) to normalize your store .